# naturalWidth value of img return window.innerWidth value

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg, safari

I have svg image with sizes 92x21 `<svg width="28" height="106" viewBox="0 0 28 106" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">`

I add it on the page using img tag with onload handler where I read naturalWidth of loaded image and set this value to iconWidth variable.

```
<img
  src={widget.src.image}
  style={`width: ${iconWidth}px !important;`}
  onload={onImageLoad}
/>
```

This is work fine mostly img have sizes 92x21, but sometimes naturalWidth of loaded image return value equal to window.innerWidth value, so the image become as big as window sizes.

I can`t always reproduce this bug but most often this happened after resize page in Safari browser on ios devices. Reproduce on iPhone 7 ios 15.4 (naturalWidth: 375) and iPhone 11 ios 15.5 (naturalWidth: 414)

[image]